# Powershell send-MailMessage Exception

Tags: powershell, exchange, office365

My script for sending emails using Office365 with an admin credentials. The script worked about 6 month, ago but recently it has not been working although it has not been changed.

I have tried to remove UseSsl but it did not work.

```
try {

    Send-MailMessage -To "myemail@domain.com" -Subject "test" `
        -From "support@domain.com" `
        -SmtpServer 'smtp.office365.com' -Port 587 -UseSsl:$true `
        -Credential $Cred -Body "testbody"
    Write-Host "Message sent to me." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch [System.Exception] {
    throw $_
}
```

Here is the exception I get:

> Send-MailMessage : Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. The credential used does not have permissions to send email as `support@domain.com` in  `-From "support@domain.com"`

Comment: Nice job solving that on your own.

Comment: How did you actually find the problem?

Comment: Well done you solved the issue :)

Comment: The following link might be helpful to others with the same issue: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just tried the admin email (the credential used to connect to exchange in the above powershell script) for the `-From` line instead of `support@domain.com` and that worked. Admin credentials did not have permissions to send email on behalf of (or as) `support@domain.com`.